# Is it possible to add description to qemu VMs?

Tags: ps, qemu

Is it possible to add description to `qemu` virtual machines? I mean something similar to `qemu -enable-kvm -description "RHEL test-host" ...`. This would allow one to easily identify virtualized hosts in `ps` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify the virtual machines with the `-name Ubuntu16.04` option (for example), that should do it - it is kinda like a description of the virtual machine you are installing.

Also, when you create the VM, there is a description field where you can add the desired and longer description, rather than sticking to a name where only alphanumeric characters and '.-_' is allowed.
But I'm not sure that you can obtain this description from the `ps` output....probably you can obtain it from `virsh` or maybe the VM config `xml` files in the `/etc/libvirt/qemu/` folder.

Do something like :

```
for i in $(ps -ef | grep qemu-system | grep -e "-name" | awk '{print $11}')
do 
  sudo grep "<description>" /etc/libvirt/qemu/$i.xml \
    | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1
done
```

and this will display for you the description of the running virtual machines (tested on Ubuntu 14.04).
Instead of parsing the config file, you can also dump it with `virsh` (use this line in the `for` loop) :

```
sudo virsh dumpxml $i | grep description | cut -d'>' -f2 | cut -d'<' -f1
```

If the VM has no description, it won't display anything for that VM.